# Check if binary was build from the same source

Tags: compiler-construction

Say you want to recompile a binary and you want to make sure all code which makes it into the binary has not been tampered with and is also in some other official build.

Is there some way to check if a binary has been build from the same (or similar) sources? Reproducible builds could be an option but I have non reproducible ones in mind. So there will always be some minor differences. How many differences would you expect? Can you do binary diffing in a reasonable way so to be fairly sure no foreign code has been added?

Comment: I would reason the pure binary could always be tampered with in a minor way which you would consider *too much*, but not detect it. Imagine a couple of `noop` slides here and there and running an executable from somewhere else. If your executable always looks a little different, it might just as well be a self-compiling computer-virus.

Comment: Have you ever encountered Dennis Ritchie's Reflections on Trusting Trust?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: you mean Ken Thompson, not Dennis. (No relation to me, BTW.) OP: A _complete_ solution to this would solve the Halting Problem and is clearly impossible, but at the other end of scale quite a few simple cases are clearly possible. I have no idea how often actual cases would be simple enough.